# Sorting of list<object> in ascending and descending order using linq in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, list, generic-list

Hello guys I am getting resopnse from web api and storing it on var "obj1". then adding it to list "snap" of object type...i have to perform an operation on "snap" so that list should come in ascending order according to one parameter like "distance"....please help me

here is my code..

```
List<object> snap = new List<object>();
var obj1 = objEntity.TB_Broadcast_Snap.Where(s => s.snapid == sid)
                                      .Join(objEntity.TB_User_Registration,
                                            u => u.userid,
                                            v => v.userid,
                                            (u, v) => new { TB_Broadcast_Snap = u, TB_User_Registration = v })
                                      .Select(s => new
                                      {
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.snapid,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.title,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.details,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.category,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.tag,

                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.broadcastdistance,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.images,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.latitude,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.longitude,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.image_detail1,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.image_detail2,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.image_detail3,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.barcode_image,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.broadcast_date,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.promocode,
                                          snaptitle = s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.title,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.broadcasttype,
                                          s.TB_Broadcast_Snap.regionname,
                                          distance = 0,
                                          popcountno = popcount,
                                          issnaped = issnapped,
                                          //Vendor Detail
                                          s.TB_User_Registration.emailid,
                                          address1 = "No address",

                                          s.TB_User_Registration.userid,
                                          s.TB_User_Registration.username,
                                          s.TB_User_Registration.imageurl,
                                          s.TB_User_Registration.business_name,
                                          s.TB_User_Registration.vendortype,
                                          vendorname = s.TB_User_Registration.name,
                                      }).ToList();
snap.AddRange(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to order first by `Distance` and then descending by another field:

```
var obj1 = objEntity.TB_Broadcast_Snap.Where(s => s.snapid == sid)
                                       .Join(/*code*/)
                                       .Select(/*code*/)
                                       .OrderBy(item => item.Distance)
                                       .ThenByDescending(item => item.OtherField)
                                       .ToList();
```

Comment: there is column name as distance that i have created dynamically it doesn't mention as property it's dynamic and i have to sort this result in ascending according to this

Comment: @amitsingh - Ya it's fine - it is a field in the objects returned from the `select`

Comment: what is snap in your answer is it list or variable??  or can u give me proper code ...that will be great help thank u brother

Comment: @amitsingh - snap is exactly your list from your code - What I'm saying is that you don't need to declare it, initialize it with a new empty list and then do AddRange - but just directly declare it an have it reference to the result of the linq

Comment: thanks but actully this is if else condition so some records are coming from  if and some are coming from else then i am inserting this record in list...so all i want to know that can i operate ascending operation on this list

Comment: @amit - ah ok :) so still it is in the answer haha

Comment: sorry bro..it might be possible that i can't see that thing...but suppose i am getting some data in within for loop and checking condition, within  if condition based on some condition inserted  that data in snap list then loop continues and now it goes to else condition and get some data and inserted that data in that list again now i have to make this list in ascending order.. id on't know what should i do???

Comment: @amitsingh - I didn't really understand what you are saying but the code above explains how to do both the ascending and descending ordering so it should be good for you

Comment: can i transefer data of snap list in another list in ascending order?

Comment: but property is not accessible bcoz it is not available in class

Comment: yes .. i have to use another class to manage it ...i didn't had another option to solve this thing...thanx @Gilad Green...that's a great help from you